# how to insert into multiple tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

i am trying to insert into multiple tables using rails..
i have a table called users and services.
when i create a user the user details should go into users and a service name and userid should go into services table.
Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a callback to create a new service when a user is created.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def after_create
        Service.create!(:name => 'my_service_name', :user_id => self.id)
    end
end
```

The after_create method is triggered after a new user creation. So a new service will be created every time you create a new user.

You can find more informations about the callbacks on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use accept_nested_attributes_for:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :service
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :service
end

User.create(:name => "Example User", :service_attributes => {:name => "Example Service"})
```

Filling in the service_attributes hash is made simple with nested forms.